# How test parent protected method calling (count)

Tags: testing, inheritance, mocking

I am trying to test this kind of code:

```
class SMTPAppenderBase<ILoggingEvent>{

   protected void append(ILoggingEvent e){
      //someCode
      //someCode
      sendBuffer();
      //someCode
   }

   protected void sendBuffer(){
      //SomeCode
   }
}
```

---

```
class SMTPAppender extends SMTPAppenderBase<ILogging>{

   //someMethod
}
```

---

```
class CustomAppender extends SMTPAppender{

   protected void append(ILoggingEvent e){
      //someCode
      //someCode
      super.append(e)
      //someCode
   }
}
```

I need to test **how many times super.append(e) is calling from CustomAppender**. This must be done in @Test method.

How should I do this? I thought about:

- Mockito --> mock/spy. But it seems to be difficult with parent AND protected method.
- Anonym class into CustomAppender -->

  ```
  CustomAppender appender = new CustomAppender() {

          @Override
          protected void sendBuffer() {
              //my counter here
              super.sendBuffer();
          }
      };
  ```

Comment: I've rollback your edit: please do not include a solution in the question itself. Instead, find your solution in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53372751/revisions) and post it as an answer of its own.